# Company's departments (offices): New York's department (office) or New York department (office)

Tags: possessives

What is the proper way to list company's departments (offices) which are located in several cities?

- New York's department: +1-212-123...
- San Francisco's department: +1-415-321...

or

- New York department: +1-212-123...
- San Francisco department: +1-415-321...

Is the `'s` in the end of the city's name required?

Comment: Though not ungrammatical, the former style is hardly normal.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth you think the first form is more "ear-friendly" (for a native speaker)?

Comment: You are listing the information, so ear-friendliness is a minor concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possessive form certainly seems odd in British English. I would say that (at least in British English) the non-possessive form is by far the most prevalent form: almost universally so.

I would argue that the possessive form is incorrect because the departments do not ***belong*** to the cities, but are ***located*** in the cities: the place name is an ***adjective*** describing or identifying the particular department.  The departments ***belong*** to the company - hence the company's name should be in the possessive form, but not the location:   "company's New York department".